# Showing a javascript app on a page on github.io

Tags: javascript, github-pages

I made a simple Openprocessing sketch in javascript using PJ5.js, which can be found here: https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/522642

However, I want to import some different libraries, which the free version of openProcessing doesn't allow. So my next step was to host the sketch using the free github.io pages.

However, after countless hours of searching, I can't really find a tutorial on how to do this. Anyone has a clue on how to host this javascript sketch on github.io instead of on Openprocessing? Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can host static pages on github and the setup is really simple. Just go to [Github pages](https://pages.github.com/), scroll down and you will find all the info you need. However you will have to create an html page to run your script. You can't just paste your javascript and run it.

Comment: Thanks, could you point me in the direction of where to find more info about doing this?